# Why are there green pulses surrounding me at apparently random times?

Tags: wildstar

Fairly often while playing I see green waves apparently emanating from my character.  I can be running, standing still, etc. and I see no obvious reason for it.  What does this mean?

Comment: Where are you currently? Are you in the Jungle by any chance?

Comment: I was in the initial area after the ship, Everstar Grove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the early quest chain in Everstar Grove.  When you land, the NPC that greets you talks about all the wildlife being crazed.  Once you progress past a certain point in the zone story, that effect goes away.